# MakeSignature.signDetached performance improvement

Tags: pdf, itext, electronic-signature

I am using `MakeSignature.signDetached` method to add digital signature in PDF.
I do sign the PDF in bulk, it works, but after each method call I have to write `Thread.Sleep(500)` in order to continue the process, if I do not use `Thread.sleep(500)` I have to replug the usb dongle.

This process takes more time to process hundreds of PDFs.

In a nutshell, I would like to know:

1. How to improve the performace?
2. how can I ignore `Thread.Sleep` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tiny smart card in your USB dongle. Many smart cards have a built-in limitation that allows you to create only one signature per second. That's why you have to use `Thread.sleep(500)`.

You can't improve the performance using code. If you want to improve the performance, you need to change your hardware. For instance: replace your USB dongle with a Hardware Security Module (HSM).

This is not a question about (or for) iText. This is a question you should ask the provider of your security hardware. Buy hardware that is suited to process hundreds of PDFs instead of using a USB dongle that is created to sign documents manually, *not* in batch.

Comment: Dear Bruno Thanks a Ton for your expert advice and we had talk with vendor and they have suggested to purchase below device for bulk processing.Once agian Thanks for help!,http://10.16.18.155/attachment/03/store/2014/07/16/16/46/557/Luna_SA_PB_%28EN%29_v3_Apr122013_web.pdf